# Stylesheet manifest in rails doesn't respond to some `require _____` lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Why isn't the usual `//*= require name_of_thing` in the stylesheet manifest (application.css.scss) working? I have to separately include `@import name_of_thing` instead.

---

For example, the select2 gem instructions (https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) says to type

```
*= require select2
*= require select2-bootstrap
```

in the application.css.scss file

But it has no effect. Instead, I have to type

```
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";
```

I've tried including both, including one, including the other, removing both, and through testing concluded the commented out require has no effect, and only the @import directive has effect.

Why does this happen in my rails? What am I configuring incorrectly?

---

Also, what should be getting handled by `*= require tree .` aren't getting included in my browser too

For example, I have a character scaffold. On the show view for character, the css in charater.css.scss is not getting loaded into the browser. Instead, I have to manually @import `"characters"` instead. Why is this?

However, `*= require_self` works.

---

My entire application.css.scss file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
@import "resets";
@import "bootstrap";
/* blanket styles */
@import "custom/cp_variables";
@import "custom/cp_custom";
@import "custom/cp_responsive";
/* controller-specific styles */
@import "socionics";
@import "characters";
@import "comments";
@import "votes";
/* plugin styles */
@import "spritz";
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";
/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require tree .
 */
```

Comment: Should work. What do the logs say when you type: `/* *= require name_of_thing */`

Comment: should it be `require_tree` rather than `reuire tree` for the css manifest? I didn't notice any difference.

Comment: As to your question, I'm not sure which part of the logs I should be looking at. I can do browser dev tools and see if a particular css file in in the page

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug remotely. My recommendation is to get rid of the `@import` completely.

Try:

```
/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Note the order, `require_tree` and commenting style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried fixing the `_`, and getting rid of the other stylesheets. But doing this, and getting rid of `
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";` still doesn't look the way they should (i.e. with select2 and select2-bootstrap stylesheets included).